# Where should I ask this question about Expression Studio licensing?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

> In the past, there's been an issue with Microsoft not allowing you to deactivate an Expression Studio key. Basically, you get two licenses. If you assign them both (say one to a desktop and one to a laptop), then you upgrade to a new machine (say you replace your laptop), you have to buy a new copy of Expression Studio ($600 for Ultimate). This seems ludicrous to me, and I'm wondering if anyone knows if this policy is still in place. I can't seem to find a EULA online anywhere, so I don't know where to find this information. I know my laptop is due for replacement soon, and I want to know if I'm going to have to sink $600 into a software product I already purchased.

Is there an appropriate StackExchange forum for the above question?

Answer (score 2):

This question can be posted on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Thanks. Just posted my question there (http://superuser.com/questions/231513/what-is-the-latest-on-expressoin-studio-licensing).